# Why do my pointers print different addresses?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I'm trying to learn about pointers and I've hit a bit of a wall.  I don't know why some of my print statements are printing a certain way.  More details next to the code as a comment.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {

};

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *second = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    tail = new Node();

    Node** node_ref = &head;

    cout << head << endl; //memory address of head
    cout << &head << endl; //prints an address different than the line above? Why?
    cout << node_ref << endl; //prints the same as cout << &head;
    cout << &node_ref << endl; //prints new address (Is this the address of the new pointer?)
    cout << *node_ref << endl; //prints the same as cout << head; Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every object has its own address.  A pointer is an object that can store the address of another object.

Comment: The value of `head` is a pointer to a `Node` object on the heap. But `head` itself (the pointer) is on the stack, and `&head` points to its location.

Comment: *"prints the same as cout << head; Why?"* -- why is this a surprise? You initialized `node_ref = &head`, so does it not make sense that applying indirection to both sides preserves the equality? `node_ref == &head` implies `*node_ref == *(&head)`, which simplifies to `*node_ref == head`. So, yes, printing `*node_ref` *should* give the same result as printing `head`.